# React JS 18 auto refresh fetching data refresh error

Tags: reactjs

I have created an app **npx create-react-app** (React JS 18 version).

Node JS server is: http://localhost:5000/

React JS server is: http://localhost:3000/

Using this function for fetching data from **node server**.

```
export function getAllProducts() {
return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch(setStatus(STATUSES.ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST));

        const data = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");
        dispatch(setStatus(STATUSES.ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS));
        console.log("data - ", data);

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(setStatus(STATUSES.ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL));
        console.log("data error - ", error);  
    }
}
```

}

and this function invoked here

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProducts());
},[]);
```

whenever page is auto refresh then ERROR coming

*GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products 500 (Internal Server Error)*

but whenever **I Refresh whole page data is coming from node server**.

Comment: What do you mean by auto refresh?

Comment: configure base url  as  API url in axios

Answer (score 0):

> > replace localhost with 127.0.0.1

GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/products
---------

Comment: Jigar, you need to tell us why you think using `127.0.0.1` would work and be any different from `localhost`.